# Validador de JTextField solo letras

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer un validador de caracteres ingresados en un `JTextField` con la acción `keyTyped` de esta forma:

```
char caracter=evento.getKeyChar();
if(((caracter<'a') || (caracter>'z')) && ((caracter<'A') || (caracter>'Z'))){
  evento.consume();
}
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de que tome en cuenta también la tecla espacio

Answer (score 1):

Marcel,

Revisando [docs de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), parece que deberías usar el método `evento.getKeyCode()` (int), y lo que te retorne, compararlo con `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE`, ya que, según entiendo, getKeyChar() no funciona para todo evento del teclado, solo los que generan caracteres. Aunque igual deberías poder compararlo con `' '`, no?

Encontré un [ejemplo](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.awt.event.KeyEvent&method=getKeyCode), a ver si te sirve